# Solomon Golomb's infinite tree

Tags: probability, information-theory

Let us construct a tree G(M). It's constructed in the following manner: 
The left line maps into A(M), the right line get's us to spot k1. The left line from k1 maps to A(M), the right line to k2. etc..

A(M) is the optimal tree for p=(1/M,1/M,..,1/M)
Let now M=4

-What's the average sequence of 1's and 0's?
-If we found that the average length of a bitchain of 1's or 0's is 1/p. What's the compressionfactor? 
-How do we compare this p=1/6 (the best possible compressionfactor)?

I had a start for the first one... I thought the solution was (3+q^/(1-q^4)). But I have no idea how to derive it.